# What is different between localhost(127.0.0.1) and remote server ip on node web server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I try to know web server based Node.js with ubuntu server. I set "localhost" in host variable at first, however, it's not working when I access remote server such as http://192.168.0.11:3000. so, I changed variable data to "192.168.0.11". It's working on browser.
I checked ubuntu firewall, port number, telnet on my local desktop. Could I know how it work on IP addr.

```
var http = require('http');
const host = '192.168.0.11';
// const host = 'localhost'; or '127.0.0.1';

http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.end('Hello world!');
}).listen(3000, host);

console.log('Server is running at',host,':3000');
```

Comment: If you set the host variable to 'localhost', you need to access the website at http://localhost:3000. When providing a hostname, the server listens for requests directed at that hostname

Comment: @rickjerrity oups... I had less understand about it.thanks for teach important thing.